# Build a dictionary using select values from a different dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary with years as keys and other dictionaries as values (these inner dictionaries contain tuples (i, i+1) as keys). An example of the format would be:

```
myDict = {2000: {(0,1):111.1, (1,2):222.2, (2,3):333.3, (3,4):444.4}
          2001: {(0,1):11.1, (1,2):22.2, (2,3):33.3, (3,4):44.4}}
```

From this dictionary, I am trying to compile a dictionary, `secondDict`, that also has years for keys. The values will be the sum of the innermost values in `myDict` for only certain tuples (i.e. any tuple in that year whose 0th index is greater than 1). What I am going for is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
secondDict = {2000: 777.7, 2001: 77.7}
```

The value in `secondDict` would be the sum of the values in `myDict[2000][tuple]` if the 1st number in the tuple was greater than or equal to `2`.

So far I have:

```
years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
tuples = [(i, i+1) for i in range(65)]

for year in years:
    for key in myDict[year]:
        for value in myDict[year][key]:
            if key[0] >= 30:
                secondDict[year] += value
```

I have several problems with my method here, but can't think of another way to build the dictionary.

1) Firstly, I'm getting a `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` for the third line of the loop (`for value in` ...). All the values that I am trying to access are floats, so I'm not sure how to work around this.

2) Moving on to problems I anticipate but haven't been able to address due to the `TypeError`: In the line `if key[0] >= 30` I am trying to access the 0th index of the tuple; will this work / if not, how do I access it?

3) I am working with some fairly large dictionaries here and it seems like the running time for this many loops will be quite slow; however I'm pretty new to coding so my grasp of this is limited. Is it just **O(n)** for each loop, i.e. **O(n^4)** since there are four loops? How can I create a better, quicker algorithm to build a dictionary like this?

***EDIT:***

After more research and some finicking with the code, I now have:

```
for year in years:
    for key in myDict[year].keys():
        if key[0] >= 30:
            secondDict[year] += myDict[year][key]
```

This doesn't raise any errors, but upon printing it I find that it only compiles for one year:

```
In[5]: secondDict
Out[5]: 
defaultdict(None,
            {2000: 0,
             2001: 0,
             2002: 0,
             2003: 27162828.602349777,
             2011: 0,
             2012: 0,
             2013: 0,
             2014: 0})
```

Why is it not iterating fully over `years`? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the meaning of `any interval in that year whose 1st index is greater than 30)`

Comment: Sorry that was confusing. I want to access the inner keys of `myDict` (the tuples) and extract values for only those tuples (I thought of them as intervals) with high enough values. So, for example, if `myDict[2000]` had the keys `(28, 29), (29, 30), (30, 31), (31, 32)` I would want to extract the values under `(30, 31) and (31, 32)` but not `(28,29) and (29,30)`. I'll go back and try to phrase it better

Comment: But in the above problem, none of the tuple values are `>30` so How come the answer to be 777.7

Comment: It was just a bit of a typo. The actual dictionary is very long so I gave a condensed version in my question - the inconsistency arose because `30` is the cut off I'm trying to use in my actual dictionary. The actual dictionary has years 2000-2003 and 2011-2014, and tuples (i, i+1) for i from 0 to 64. I tried to clarify better in my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dict comprehension that performs the action you specify at the start of your question, i.e., the values are the sum of the innermost values in `myDict` for tuples whose 0th index is greater than 1.

```
myDict = {
    2000: {(0,1):111.1, (1,2):222.2, (2,3):333.3, (3,4):444.4},
    2001: {(0,1):11.1, (1,2):22.2, (2,3):33.3, (3,4):44.4},
}

secondDict = {y: sum(v for t, v in d.items() if t[0] > 1) 
    for y, d in myDict.items()}
print(secondDict)
```

**output**

```
{2000: 777.7, 2001: 77.69999999999999}
```